# Latex arrows around corner tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I'm experiencing some troubles with Latex and the arrows in the tilkzpicture-environment. Can someone help me how to close the arrow on the bottom? I tried different things such as --|, |-, –| but it won't work

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, right=10mm]{article}
 \usepackage    [english]{babel} 
 \usepackage{marvosym} 
\usepackage{eurosym} 
 \usepackage[labelfont=bf,textfont=it, font=small]{caption} 
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
 \usepackage{fancyhdr} 
 \setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
  \usepackage{setspace}
  \setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
\usepackage{flowchart} \usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning,fit,calc}
    \usepackage{amsmath, multicol, color, longtable} 
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, node distance=7mm, %thick,
  typetag/.style={rectangle, draw=black!50, font=\scriptsize, anchor=west}
]
\center{

\node (A2) at (0,0) [title]{\underline{Training set}};

\node (A3) [below= of A2.west, typetag] {$\mathbf{x}_{2N/10 \, +1}$, ... $\mathbf{x}_{{3N}{/10}}$};
\node (A7) [below=of A3.west, typetag] {...};
\node (A6) [below=of A7.west, typetag] {$\mathbf{x}_{9N/10 \, +1}$, ... $\mathbf{x}_{N}$};

  \node (A1) [draw=double, double distance 1pt, thick, fit={(A2) (A3) (A7) (A6)} ] {};

\node (B1) [right= of A3.west, xshift=4cm ]{\underline{Coefficients:}};
\node (B2) [below= of B1.center, typetag, xshift=-0.5cm ] {$\hat{\beta}^{test}$};

\node (B3) [draw, thick, fit={(B1) (B2)} ] {};

\node (C1) [right= of B1.right, xshift=1cm ] [title]{\underline{Test set}};
\node (C2) [below= of C1.west, typetag] {$\mathbf{x}_{1}$, ... $\mathbf{x}_{{N}{/10}}$};

  \node (C3) [draw=double, double distance 1pt, thick, fit={(C1) (C2)} ] {};

\node (D1) [right= of C1.right, xshift=1cm ] [title]{\underline{Mean-squared Error}};
\node (D2) [below= of D1.west, typetag] {$\mathbf{\hat{y}}_{1}-\mathbf{y}_1$, ... , $\mathbf{\hat{y}}_{{N}{/10}}-\mathbf{y}_{N/10}$};
  \node (D3) [draw=double, double distance 1pt, thick, fit={(D1) (D2)} ] {};


\node (z) [below= of D3.center, yshift=-1.5 cm]{};
\node (z1) [below = of C3.center, yshift=-2cm]{};
\node (z2) [below= of A1.south, yshift=-0.5cm]{};

\draw[->] (A1) -- node[above] {lasso} (B3)(B3) ;
\draw[->] (C3) -- (z1) -- node[above] {permute test and training sets} (z2) -| (A1); 
\draw[->] (B3) -- (C3);
\draw[->] (C3) -- (D3);
\node (X) [draw=double, double distance 1pt, thick, fit={(A1) (B3) (C3) (D3) (z1) (z2)} ] {};


}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The diagramme shows the function of the crossvalidation}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What packages do you use?

Comment: Sorry, I had some troubles with adjusting the code, I'm actually very familiar with Latex, but the Tikz-environment is making me crazy.

Comment: I wouldn't use nodes as coordinates in your case. It is sufficient to draw like this: \draw[->] (C3) -- +(0,-2) node[above, xshift=-3cm] {permute test and training sets} -| (A1);

Answer (score 4):

The reason you have gaps in that line, is that you're drawing lines between `nodes`. When drawing a line to a node, the line stops at the edge of a node. Try for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {};
\node (b) at (1,0) {};
\node (c) at (2,0) {};
\draw (a) -- (b) -- (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You get a gap in the line because it stops at the left edge of `b`, and starts again on the right edge of `b`. To fix that, use the `center` anchor:

```
\draw (a) -- (b.center) -- (c);
```

Or define them as `\coordinate`s instead of `\node`s, i.e. `\coordinate (b) at (1,0);`. In other words this is a working definition:

```
\draw[->] (C3) -- (z1.center) -| (A1);
```

You do not need `z2` as well. `z1` is directly below `C3`, so draw a straight line there, and then use `-|` to draw first horizontally to directly below `A1`, and then straight up.

Alternatively you could avoid defining the `z`-nodes, by using

```
 \draw[->] (C3) -- ++(0,-3cm) -| (A1);
```

There are several other problems with your code though, surely you must get a lot of errors from it:

- Have you defined the `title` style somewhere else? I added just an empty definition here.
- `draw=double,double distance 1pt` should be `draw,double,double distance=1pt` I'd think.
- `B1.right` should be `B1.east`. There is no anchor called `right`.
- Place all the options inside the same brackets, e.g. `[right=of A,title]`, instead of `[right=of A][title]`.
- `\center{ ... }` doesn't make sense inside a `tikzpicture`, it causes an error, and I think it should be used as `\begin{center} .. \end{center}`.
- Don't specify the driver (`[pdftex]`) for `graphicx`. The package figures out on it's own, so use just

  ```
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  ```

  (Or remove it altogether, as it's also loaded by TikZ.)

I also set the superscript `test` as `\mathrm`, and used e.g. `$x_1, \dots, x_N$` instead of `$x_1$, ..., $x_N$`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  >=stealth,
  node distance=7mm, 
  title/.style={},
  thick, typetag/.style={rectangle, draw=black!50, font=\scriptsize, anchor=west}
 ] 

\node (A2) at (0,0) {\underline{Training set}};
\node (A3) [below=of A2.west, typetag] {$\mathbf{x}_{2N/10 , +1}, \dots,\mathbf{x}_{{3N}{/10}}$}; \node (A7) [below=of A3.west, typetag] {\dots};
\node (A6) [below=of A7.west, typetag] {$\mathbf{x}_{9N/10 , +1}, \dots, \mathbf{x}_{N}$};
\node (A1) [draw,double, double distance=1pt, thick, fit={(A2) (A3) (A7) (A6)} ] {};

\node (B1) [right=4.7cm of A3.west]{\underline{Coefficients:}};
\node (B2) [below= of B1.center, typetag, xshift=-0.5cm ] {$\hat{\beta}^{\mathrm{test}}$};
\node (B3) [draw, thick, fit={(B1) (B2)} ] {};

\node (C1) [right=1.7cm of B1.east, title]{\underline{Test set}};
\node (C2) [below=of C1.west, typetag] {$\mathbf{x}_{1},\dots, \mathbf{x}_{{N}{/10}}$};
\node (C3) [draw,double, double distance=1pt, thick, fit={(C1) (C2)} ] {};

\node (D1) [right=1.7cm of C1.east,title]{\underline{Mean-squared Error}};
\node (D2) [below=of D1.west, typetag] {$\mathbf{\hat{y}}_{1}-\mathbf{y}_1,\dots, \mathbf{\hat{y}}_{{N}{/10}}-\mathbf{y}_{N/10}$};
\node (D3) [draw,double, double distance=1pt, thick, fit={(D1) (D2)} ] {};

\node (z) [below=-2.2cm of D3.center]{};
\node (z1) [below=2.7cm of C3.center]{};
\node (z2) [below=1.2 of A1.south]{};

\draw[->] (A1) -- node[above] {lasso} (B3.west |- A1.east);
%\draw[->] (C3) -- (z1.center) -| (A1);
\draw[->] (C3) -- ++(0,-3cm) -| (A1);
\draw[->] (B3) -- (C3);
\draw[->] (C3) -- (D3);

\node (X) [double, double distance=1pt, thick, fit={(A1) (B3) (C3) (D3) (z1) (z2)} ] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Tjorbjørn, thank you for the help. I see the problem with using nodes instead of coordinates. I thought it was the same. And I didn't know that I had to use the math environment, since it was working either way! ANYWAY; THANK YOU A LOT!!!!

Comment: @Simona I added a couple of extra points to my answer, and edited the code a bit more. Well, the `$x_1$, ... $x_N$` part is working, but I think `$x_1,\dots,x_N$` is more semantically correct.

Comment: That's true, anyway, it's fine, I had to add "draw=" into all the boxes where I wanted to have a double frame, like in your picture, otherwise there was no frame at all. But this must be something to do with the other packages I used.

Comment: @Simona I don't follow, what must be to do with other packages?

Comment: When I copied your code and pasted it into my longer document, after compiling I had exactly the same image as above except for the frames around 'Test set', ‘Training Set‘ and ‘Mean Squared error‘. So I added 

node (C3) [draw=double, double distance=1pt, thick, fit={(C1) (C2)} ] {}; 
But I guess, you've already changed that! - sorry for causing confusions